# PreferenceActivity inside a Sliding menu

Tags: android, slidingmenu, preferenceactivity

Currently i am developing an app that needs to have a sliding menu but inside that sliding-menu i want to have a preference activity style like , for example like YouTube app sliding menu style.

I am working with "jfeinstein" sliding menu because i didn't found something else to make the sliding menu and it's not offering a way to make a activity in the sliding menu.

So is there another sliding menu library or is there actually a way to do what i described?

Thanks